# Creating Conditional States with JOptionPane Buttons

Tags: java, joptionpane

Is there a way that I could create separate conditional statements for the ok and cancel button in `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`?
The reason I want to do this is because I don't want an empty string or a string just full of spaces to be set to `s`.
When I click ok with an empty text field or just click cancel, `s` would be set to null.
Is there a way that I can choose different options for the ok and cancel button to where if I were to click cancel, the window would close and if I were to click ok, the code would proceed with the conditional statements?

```
public boolean stringIsNullOrOnlyWhiteSpaces(String s)  {
   //checks if string is null or if string only contains white spaces
}


private void nameOfString() {
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter String Name");

if (!stringIsNullOrOnlyWhiteSpaces(s)) {
   // do action    
  }

else { // if "ok" were to be clicked and not "cancel"
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "String cannot be empty");
nameOfString();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: In your example code, you could have a message dialog on top of the input dialog.  If you create your own JDialog, you can have the JTextField and the JLabel message in the same dialog.  Since you're creating the JDialog, you control what happens when the OK and Cancel buttons are left clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there's a way where you can get just using `JOptionPane`, they're supposed just to catch a value, in the case of `.showInputMessage()` it's a string.

The right way would be using `JDialog` and adding components with its logic inside it.

I'm really bored at job so I did something that I think would work for you:

```
public class CustomInput {

private JButton btAccept;
private JButton btCancel;
private JLabel lbInput;
private JTextField tfInput;
private JPanel pnDialog;

private JPanel createPanel() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;
    pnDialog = new JPanel();
    lbInput = new JLabel();
    tfInput = new JTextField();
    btAccept = new JButton();
    btCancel = new JButton();

    pnDialog.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    btAccept.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btAcceptAction(evt);
        }
    });

    btCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btCancelAction(evt);
        }
    });

    lbInput.setText("Enter your input.");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    pnDialog.add(lbInput, gridBagConstraints);

    tfInput.setText("");
    tfInput.setColumns(10);
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    pnDialog.add(tfInput, gridBagConstraints);

    btAccept.setText("Accept");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    pnDialog.add(btAccept, gridBagConstraints);

    btCancel.setText("Cancel");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    pnDialog.add(btCancel, gridBagConstraints);

    return pnDialog;
    //Mommy someone is reading my code
}

private void btAcceptAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (tfInput.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pnDialog, "Input cannot be null", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

private void btCancelAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JDialog topFrame = (JDialog) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(pnDialog);
    topFrame.dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    CustomInput tp = new CustomInput();
    dialog.add(tp.createPanel());
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

}
```